# Add a picture into a grid - ExtJS

Tags: html, extjs, grid, image

i'm (very) new to ExtJS, and I'm trying to add a picture into one of the fields of my grid.
I've already looking for some results or tips on Google, I found out the "render function" but it doesn't work (I mean, maybe I'm just using it wrong)

Here's my code :

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.userlist',
  title: 'Test ',
  store: 'Users',
  initComponent: function() {
    this.columns = [
   {header: 'ID du CPE', dataIndex: 'ID',  flex: 1},
       {header: 'Modèle', dataIndex: 'Modele', flex: 1},
   {header: 'Firmware', dataIndex: 'firmware', flex: 1},
   {header: 'Année MeS', dataIndex: 'annee', flex: 1},
       {header: 'Statut', dataIndex: 'statut', flex: 1},
   {header: 'Alerte', dataIndex: 'alerte', flex: 1}   
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

A Json File populate all these fields, except 'Alerte'.
And this is where I would like to add a picture (no text in this field, only a picture).

Thanks by advance, I hope i've been clearest as possible !

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) to your column config:

```
{header: 'Alerte', dataIndex: 'alerte', flex: 1, renderer: function() {
return '<img src="blablabla"/>';
}}
```

Refer to the documentation to see what arguments renderer gets so that you can customize your image according to the actual record if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `actioncolumn` for show icons in your cells in grid and use `renderer` function to put icons into cells. Good rule to use css classes in your application.
Here's my simple example:

```
                   {
                        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                        width: 70,
                        align: 'center',
                        dataIndex: 'yourDataIndex',
                        menuDisabled: 'true',
                        text: 'sometext',
                        sortable: false,
                        fixed: 'true',
                        renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                           metadata.tdCls = 'mycss'
                        }
                    }
```

and you'r css class:

```
.mycss {
    background-position:center  !important;
    width: auto !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("yourIcon.png") !important; 
}
```